# Method for getting a list async? 'List<ListDefinition>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to asp.net core programming, and trying to make a simple list application, managing a number of lists defined by ListDefinition, and each list containing several ListItems. I am trying to use async methods, which works fine when getting the ListDefinition (`var currentList = await _context.ListDefinitions.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();`)

However when trying to get the Listitems, I find no suitable method of getting it async (`var currentListItems = await currentList.ListItems.Distinct().ToListAsync();` does not exist)

### Models

```
public class ListDefinition
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid CreatedByUserGuid { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
}

public class ListItem
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set;            
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Done { get; set; }
    public bool Important { get; set; }
}
```

### Controller

```
public class CurrentListController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CurrentListController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: CurrentList/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var currentList = await _context.ListDefinitions.Where(m => m.Id == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        var currentListItems = await currentList.ListItems.Distinct().ToListAsync();
        if (currentListItems == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(currentListItems);
    }
(...)
```

The error message:

```
'List<ListDefinition>' does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and no extension method 'ToListAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'List<ListDefinition>'
```

Comment: I don't think you can use child relations async like that.  The `*Async()` extension methods only apply to EF query types.

Comment: So for a newbie, what would be the best way to work this out? Use interface/repository? Or am i overthinking and could just do it sync?

Comment: `ToListAsync()`is in `Microsoft.Data.Entity`. Do you have that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

Don't leverage lazy loading. Grab all the data in one hit:

```
var currentList = await _context.ListDefinitions.Where(m => m.Id == id)
                                .Include(ld => ld.ListItems).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

This means the data is already loaded, so there's no benefit in using async in the next call:

```
var currentListItems = await currentList.ListItems.Distinct().ToList();
```

However, since you're using a `Distinct` (what for? Perhaps there shouldn't be duplicates in the database?), you can potentially be loading too much data.

Because you don't actually *use* current list, you can simply load the items:

```
var currentListItems = _context.ListItems
                               .Where(li => li.ListDefinitionId == id)
                               .Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

This does of course mean you'll need to define the foreign key on `ListItem` to match up with `public virtual ICollection<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks, however I get a new error message now. `CS0411 The type arguments for method 'EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.Include<TEntity, TProperty>(IQueryable<TEntity>, Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: @OleKristianLosvik Sorry, I guessed the incorrect version of EF you're using (it used to be hardcoded strings) It should be `.Include(ld => ld.ListItems)`